# Warning using react redux firebase, component FirebaseConnectWrapped(Auth) is still using componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, redux-firestore

I`m making a project with react redux, connecting  to firebase and firestore, but the console shows me the warning of the image

[image: image captured from console]

I`m using react-redux-firebase 3.3.0 and react-redux 7.2.0

I really searched how to fix it but I didn`t find enything I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

I was using FirebaseConnect Component, and now this is deprecated after the version 3